# How to Create columns in txt file through pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hello I read a gzip file into dataframe and when I was create columns name I take this:
[image]

However when I read the table the result is:
[image]

My quesstion is: I want to **create 7 different columns** but I can't. Each comma is a column . How can I do that?

Comment: And make `sep=r' |,'`

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Only sep=',' Space is excessive - it breaks datetime field 'created at'.

Comment: @knagaev you are correct - I did not notice the date and assumed the OP wanted to subdivide the existing dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('part-00000.gz', compression='gzip', sep=',', name=['search_id',...,'return'], header=None)
```

You can pass column names when you read gzip files. Hope this will help.